# spring jdbctemplate hold data in map key is string and value Object

Tags: java, spring, dictionary, resultset, jdbctemplate

Hi need to hold the resultset as key value pair  key is string coming from database
and have multiple value corresponding to that keys values are also coming from database
map looking like this Map>

My Code is:

It is resultset extractor: In this I am iterating the resultset and adding it to the map.

ResultSetExtractor resultExtractor = new ResultSetExtractor() {

```
    public Object extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,
            DataAccessException {
        MyDataBean dataBean = new MyDataBean();
        List<MyDataBean > myDataBeanList = new ArrayList<MyDataBean >();
        Map<String, List<MyBean>> myMap = new HashMap<String, List<MyDataBean>>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String propertyNumber = rs.getString("PROPERTY_NUMBER");
            dataBean.setAccountNumber(rs.getLong("ACCOUNT_NUMBER"));
            dataBean.setAmount(rs.getDouble("AMOUNT"));
            myDataBeanList .add(dataBean);
            myMap .put(propertyNumber, argusDataList);
        }
        return myMap ;
    }
};
```

this is method::: here I am firing the query and passing the resultExtractor.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Map<String, List<MyDataBean>> getData()
        throws DataAccessException, GeneralFailureException {

    Map<String, List<MyDataBean>> myMap= null;
    try {
        myMap= jdbcTemplate.query(MyQuery,
                resultExtractor );
    } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
        throw new GeneralFailureException("SQL Exception:xyzClass::"
                + ex);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new GeneralFailureException(
                "GeneralFailureException::xyzClass::::" + ex);
    }

    return myMap;
}
```

in result set extractor I am holding data in a map but in output it is giving all keys of map but only the last value which added to the list m not getting why please help me to resolve this issue

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you actually getting multiple results such that your iteration gets multiple rows ?

Comment: Namaste Prashant.  What's the `argusDataList` variable in the question?

Comment: Sry ATG I forgot to rename it it myDataBeanList

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to extract data out of a `ResultSet` and into a mapping from each property number to its list of corresponding account information.  There is therefore a one-to-many relationship between a property number and an account.

I think you're only getting a single result because you're overwriting the key for the previous property number when you call `myMap.put(propertyNumber, list)` instead of appending to the existing list.  If you look at the Javadoc for "put(key, value)"  on `java.util.Map`, it explains that the value for any existing key in the map that matches the specified key will be replaced with the new value.

Therefore, you need to check the presence of the property number in the map using something like this:

```
if (!myMap.containsKey(propertyNumber)) {
    myMap.put(propertyNumber, new ArrayList<MyDataBean>());
}
List<MyDataBean> myDataBeanList = myMap.get(propertyNumber);
// continue constructing new MyDataBean using the current row of the ResultSet
```

I also think you need to reduce the scope of the `myDataBean` variable so that it's inside the `while (rs.next())` loop, in order to ensure that you get a distinct instance for each account number and amount.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understand this.
If you have multiple value corresponding to that keys , i would suggest code would be modified as given below. in a map , if you try to insert a key which is already existing, it replaces old value.

```
public Object extractData(ResultSet rs)  throws SQLException//, DataAccessException 
{
    MyDataBean dataBean = new MyDataBean();
    List<MyDataBean > myDataBeanList = new ArrayList<MyDataBean >();
    Map<String, List<MyDataBean>> myMap = new HashMap<String, List<MyDataBean>>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        String propertyNumber = rs.getString("PROPERTY_NUMBER");
        dataBean.setAccountNumber(rs.getLong("ACCOUNT_NUMBER"));
        dataBean.setAmount(rs.getDouble("AMOUNT"));


        if (myMap.containsKey(propertyNumber) ) 
            myMap .get(propertyNumber).add(dataBean);
        else 
        {
            myDataBeanList .add(dataBean);
            myMap.put(propertyNumber, myDataBeanList)   ;
        }
    }
    return myMap ;
}
```